# Can't find Syntax error in FROM clause Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I've been trying to find this Syntax error but can't seem to crack it (Beginner in Classic ASP) Any help would be appreciated. This is the error message:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Syntax error in FROM clause.
>
> /courses/benv/2410/2013s2/3420384/assign1/show.asp, line 29

Code:

```vbs
<% option explicit %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>default.asp</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<% dim pic
pic = request.querystring("i")
if pic="" then pic="1"

%>

<!--#include file="dbconn.asp"-->

<div class="container">

<%
 dim sql, info

'This is where the Syntax error is. 

'               0          1       2         3         4
SQL = "select Images.id, filename, location, Alphabet, Numeric "&_
    "from Images "&pic 

set info=conn.execute(SQL)

if info.eof then
response.write "<p>No Data Found</p>"
else
response.write "<p>" &_
               "id<br>" &_
               "filename<br>" &_
               "location<br>" &_
               "Alphabet<br>" &_
               "Numeric<br>" &_ 
               "Description<br>" &_
               "</p>"
do 
  response.write "<p>" &_
                 info(0) & "<br>" &_
                 "<a href=""show.asp?i=" & info(0) & """>" &_
                 "<img src=""images/" & info(1) & """></a>" &_
                 info(2) & "<br>" &_
                 info(3) & "<br>" &_ 
                 info(4) &_ 
                 "</p>"
  info.movenext
  loop until info.eof
  end if 


 conn.close
 %> 

 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What's on pic variable?

Comment: What is `pic`?  What does the resolved SQL string look like (meaning, if you invoked `Response.Write SQL`, what would be printed out?

Comment: @Oscar  I will post the whole code in the question.

Comment: So what is `pic` supposed to be doing?  That's where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

So, first off, using values passed in on your QueryString opens yourself up to SQL Injection - you should really move to parameterized queries.

Also, based on your comment, if the `i` QueryString parameter is empty, then `pic` is `1`.  Which would make your SQL statement:

`select Images.id, filename, location, Alphabet, Numeric from Images 1`

That `1` at the end doesn't make sense, which is why your page is erroring out.  If you're trying to set a WHERE clause, you'll need to fill that out more.  ADO won't complete that for you.

Do you want your SQL statement to filter out the pictures with the ID passed in via the `i` QueryString parameter?  Then your SQL should look something like:

`select Images.id, filename, location, Alphabet, Numeric from Images WHERE Images.id = 1`

And your code should look like:

```
SQL = "SELECT Images.id, filename, location, Alphabet, Numeric " & _
    "FROM Images WHERE Images.id = " & pic
```

Hope this helps!